# jquery fires function repetitive every time the window resizes - but should only once

Tags: jquery, function, resize, window, width

i want to fill empty spaces in an article list with some placeholder PNGs.
If the windowsize is 320 an there is an odd amount of items -> 1 placeholder to fill.

If the windowsize is bigger 320 and there is just one article listed or an even amount of articles is listed, one or two placeholders should be added.

Works fine, but the script always fires placeholder, everytime the windowsize changes.

Here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//the first loaded articlelist
var str = $('.item').length;
var width = $(window).width();

if ((str % 2) != 0 && width == 320) {
$('div.item').last().after('<div class="filler"></div>');
}
if ((str % 3) === 1 && width > 320) {
$('div.item').last().after('<div class="filler"></div><div class="filler"></div>');
}
if ((str  % 3) === 2 && width > 320) {
$('div.item').last().after('<div class="filler"></div>');
}

$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(this).width() != width){
        width = $(this).width()
        if ((str % 2) != 0 && $(window).width() == 320) {
        $('div.item').last().after('<div class="filler"></div>');
    }
    if ((str % 3) === 1 && $(window).width() > 320) {
        $('div.item').last().after('<div class="filler"></div><div class="filler"></div>');
    }
    if ((str  % 3) === 2 && $(window).width() > 320) {
        $('div.item').last().after('<div class="filler"></div>');
    }
    }
});
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jquery .one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) should solve your problem, it only allows a bound function to be executed once

```
$(window).one("resize", function(){...}
```